# PassivePortRange problem in IIS6 (FTP)

Tags: iis, iis-6, ftp, passive-mode

I'm trying to specify the passive port range for an ftp server running on IIS6 in Windows Server 2003.

I've used:
adsutil.vbs set /MSFTPSVC/PassivePortRange "5500-5600"

I've checked in the metabas file and the changes are applied to it.  I can also use:

adsutil.vbs get /MSFTPSVC/PassivePortRange

and it returns the range I've set.

After restarting the ftp service, restarting IIS and even rebooting, the ftp server still uses it's default range (5000-65535 AFAIK).

Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked it out.  It's a bug in the windows firewall.
If you disable the firewall, the port raneg is used properly.

I had the "FTP service" enabled in the firewall as well as the port range I wanted. I disabled the FTP service and instead added port 21 manually.  Now works fine!